# How do i encrypt resources for localization?

Tags: .net, eazfuscator

I hope someone can help me with this problem: I obfuscated my software with Eazfuscator.NET 3.2 and used encryption for symbols, strings and resources. When i look into the main dll everything looks fine, alls methods are renamed to something random. The problem is that the localized strings in my [lang]\myapp.resources.dll are still unencrypted...

I put the following code in a separate file:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "encrypt symbol names with password dummydummydummy", Exclude = false)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "string encryption", Exclude = false)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "encrypt resources", Exclude = false)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "code control flow obfuscation", Exclude = false)]
```

Can someone explain me where my mistake is?

Comment: Are the resource files (*.resx) and this ObfuscationSettings.cs file in the same project?  Are the resource files (*.resx) "Build Option"s set to "Embedded Resource" and "Custom Tool" set to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator?